# Remove a:hover from linked images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm completely desperate and can't find a solution despite of searching the www for dozens of hours.

For text links, I have added following css code:

```
a:hover img {
border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

Unfortunately this also adds a thick black underline on linkable IMGs which somehow ruins the look of my entire site.

How do I remove the border-bottom on linkable IMGs when hovered using CSS?

I've tried following codes without being able to fix the issue:

```
a img, a:hover img {
border-bottom: none !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

So far nothing worked out!

Any help regarding this issue would be highly appreciated. I know it's just a small detail – but for me it means the whole world.

Many thanks in advance!

For better understanding please have a look at:

http://www.huberthasler.de/works

The logo on the left fold out menu is affected as well.

Best wishes

m

Comment: You have to change the 'text-decoration' to 'none' for your anchor elment not for the image!

Comment: "For text links", but that's not your text-links CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that

`a:hover { border-bottom: 3px solid #000; }`

adds the border to all `a` elements on hover but the CSS rules you have in your question remove the border from `img` elements that are descendent from `a`/`a:hover` elements.  Since the `img` elements themselves never had the border, this doesn't do anything and the border on the `a` surrounding the image stays.

Seeing as you have `class="thumb-wrap"` on the main images, perhaps consider `a.thumb-wrap:hover { border-bottom: none; }`

If you need a more general solution, you will probably want to

- Tag all the image links (`a` elements containing `img`) with a particular class and set that class's `border-bottom: none;`
- Tag only text links and set that class's `border-bottom: 3px solid #000;`
- Use JavaScript to dynamically apply styles.  Using jQuery: `$('a').has('img').css('border-bottom', 'none')`

Comment: arcyqwerty, I marry you!!! The "thumb-wrap"-solution worked nicely. many many thanks for your instant help. to the other members a big hug as well and please apologize my illiteracy in terms of css etc.. best regards

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  If your problem is solved, please consider accepting my answer. :)